# Make Watir move on after waiting so long

Tags: ruby, watir

I've got some Watir code written that loads a bunch of sites from a text file and then checks to see if the page contains some certain text, some of the sites though are taking a long time to load, how do I make it so Watir waits say 10 seconds for the page to load and if it doesn't it moves on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Timeout class example on the WatirMelon page - see [here](http://watirmelon.com/2009/03/26/timing-out-watir-with-timeouttimeout/).

I tried it out with the web page below and it seems to work.

```
require 'watir'

ie = Watir::IE.new

check_url = 'http://www.nst.com.my/'

begin
    Timeout::timeout(10) do
        ie.goto(check_url)
    end
    puts 'page loaded'
rescue Timeout::Error => e
    puts 'page timed out'
end
```

You can loop your list of URLs through the above code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply but I get an error 'uninitialized constant Timeout (NameError)'. Any ideas?